# unrecognized selector sent to instance of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have the main view controller and when the `viewDidLoad` the user is validated on login via Parse and Facebook:

```
if ([PFUser currentUser] == nil && [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] == nil) {

    WelcomeViewController *welcomeController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Welcome"];
    [self presentViewController:welcomeController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

When I try to push data from the welcome view controller I use `self.presentingViewController`:

```
MainFeedTableViewController *mc = (MainFeedTableViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
mc.username = self.fbUsername;
```

**BUT**

the compiler sees it as `UINavigationController`:

`-[UINavigationController setUsername:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f92b9009a00`.

How is that possible when I am presenting with `self` of the `MainFeedTableViewController`?

Comment: self.presentingViewController just means self?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `[self presentViewController:welcomeController animated:YES completion:nil];` The presentation is done via UINavigationController (I am assuming you have a navigation controller in your application). What it does is presents the view inside its Navigation hierarchy you can use the following to get the `MainFeedTableViewController` if your `MainFeedTableViewController` is the first view in Hierarchy

```
MainFeedTableViewController * viewController = (MainFeedTableViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

If its not the first one and you want to use relative positioning you can do something like this

```
MainFeedTableViewController * viewController = (MainFeedTableViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:
                                                                                             [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self ]- 1];
```

Which will first find the Index of self (`WelcomeViewController`) and then find the view in `UINavigationController` views array a view which is just behind this one.